# Attribute as a result of operation on other attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, attributes, addition, create-table

I have 4 attributes in my table: work_price, parts_price, name and date.  I want to add a 5th attribute to this table which is total_cost as a sum of work_price and parts_price. Can I write "total_cost as (work_price + parts_price)," in my create table statement?

Can an attribute be assigned a value as a sum or difference of two other attributes in the same table?

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: "total_cost as (work_price + parts_price) is correct

Comment: try .. is more easy that post the question  .. try